# Joda Time crashes my app

Tags: android, jodatime

I'm using Joda time to get the time that has passed between 2 different dates. when i run it within my android application it seems to break the application.

this is the code that i am using

```
    Date past = new Date(110, 5, 20); // June 20th, 2010
    Date today = new Date(110, 6, 24); // July 24th 
    int days = Days.daysBetween(new DateTime(past), new DateTime(today)).getDays();
    mDateDisplay.setText(""+days);
```

any idea why this is happening and how i can solve it

Comment: What error/exception is produced? How does it break?

Comment: Please post the exception from logcat.

Comment: It seems to be working find now. unsure what was the exceptions when it happened though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use LocalDate from joda-API

```
LocalDate past = new LocalDate(2010, 5, 20);   
LocalDate today = new LocalDate (2010, 6, 24);
```